# Strange Behaviour with Custom Typeface - Not working from build

Tags: android, textview, assets, custom-font

I have a `TextView` with custom font.

```
    public class LatoBoldTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private Context mContext;

    public LatoBoldTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LatoBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LatoBoldTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Lato-Bold.ttf");
            setTypeface(typeface);

        }
    }
}
```

Then I have used this `TextView` inside my `layout.xml`, but when run it on my device from Android Studio(tested on Nexus 5 & Moto G4Plus), the textview fonts are still the default one. But then recognised that application displaying textview with custom font when relaunching from my device again.

This is the log cat I am getting.No errors, but still confusing.

```
 07-07 12:49:18.110 1152-1152/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-07 12:49:18.237 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.504 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.551 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.597 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.645 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.691 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.738 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.779 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.821 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.867 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.911 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.solver.inventory-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-07 12:49:18.918 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.solver.inventory-1/lib/arm
07-07 12:49:18.921 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-07 12:49:19.050 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-07 12:49:19.313 1152-1257/com.solver.inventory D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-07 12:49:19.377 1152-1257/com.solver.inventory I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
07-07 12:49:19.381 1152-1257/com.solver.inventory I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-07 12:49:19.441 1152-1152/com.solver.inventory W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Why this scenario? Is this going to affect my app in future? How to avoid this? 
Thanks in advance.